# How to check the log of users and applications connected to the oracle database?

Tags: database, oracle, security, audit-trail

I need to check what are the applications that are connected to the oracle database.
For that I have tried this:

```
SELECT username, machine, program
FROM v$session
WHERE type = 'USER';
```

This shows the database user, system login and application, but it is showing only currently connected connections.
I want to see complete log.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can do this through the AUDIT command. [Find out more](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_4007.htm#SQLRF01107). Depending which version of Oracle you're using ]you can audit more things in more detail](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/DBSEG/auditing.htm#DBSEG630). The most important thing about auditing is that Oracle has it switched off by default (largely for historical reasons, but all auditing imposes an overhead) so you can't check anything until you enable it.

Comment: we are using oracle 11g and we have enabled audit. I executed this: select * from SYS.AUD$ . I got log but in this information I did not get from which application the user connected. I need this also. Please help me.@APC

Answer (score 0):

you can see log through session for view session you need to open oracle Home>Administration>Database Monitor>Session
where see a log file type 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JyNUz.jpg)

Comment: we did not find the given path. https://imgur.com/a/iL28Chn @vinni mohniya